# keep getting Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. ? NextJs13 error

Tags: next.js

hello i'm new to nextjs i keep getting this error for this page followed by
Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in . i'm not quite sure what to do i even tried the [ClientOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293542/next-js-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-a-in-div-how-to) solution not sure what i'm doing wrong please note that i have other client components that are working totally fine without any errors:

```
"use client"
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
...



export default function UseNewUser() {
  // const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState('oui');
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  ....



  const handleRoleChange = (selectedRole: string) => {
    setRole(selectedRole);
  };

  // request


  return (
    <div className="p-8">
        <div className="container h-[800px] flex-col items-center justify-center ">
        <ClientOnly>
          <Dialog open>
            <DialogContent className="sm:max-w-[425px]">
              <DialogHeader>
                <DialogTitle className="mb-[1px] text-gray-500">
                  Créer un nouvel utilisateur
                </DialogTitle>
              </DialogHeader>
              <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
                <h2 className="font-bold mb-1">Informations de l’utilisateur</h2>
                  <div className="grid gap-1">
                    <Label className="text-[#98A2B3]" htmlFor="nom">
                      Nom
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      id="nom"
                      placeholder="Doe"
                      type="text"
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      autoComplete="family-name"
                      autoCorrect="off"
                      required
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setFirstName(e.target.value);
                        setFirstNameError(false);
                      }}
                    />
                    {firstNameError && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">Le nom est requis</p>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="flex justify-between gap-2">
                  <div className="grid gap-1">
                    <Label className="text-[#98A2B3]" htmlFor="email">
                      Email
                    </Label>
                    <Input
                      id="email"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      type="email"
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      autoComplete="email"
                      autoCorrect="off"
                      required
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setEmail(e.target.value);
                        setEmailError(!validateEmail(e.target.value) || false);
                      }}
                    />
                    {emailError && (
                      <p className="text-red-500">Email invalide</p>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <DialogFooter>
                <div className="flex justify-between w-full mt-2 text-gray-500">
                  <Button variant="outline">Annuler</Button>
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    className="bg-[#6F6BF4]"
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                    disabled={isSubmitDisabled}
                  >
                    Créer l’utilisateur
                  </Button>
                </div>

              </DialogFooter>
              <div className="flex justify-between w-full mt-2 text-gray-500">
                {isSubmitDisabled && (<p className="text-red-500">Tous les champs sont requis</p>)}
              </div>
            </DialogContent>
          </Dialog>
          </ClientOnly>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you fetch some data directly in the component?

Comment: yes i used a fetch request in this page

Answer (score 0):

You're fetch some data from backend in directly your component which is defined as `Client Component` so you don't directly fetch any data. You need to use `useEffect` hook

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});

useEffect(()=>{
const getData = async()=> {
 const res = await fetch("https://api.mandorakannu.tech/api/posts");
 const posts = await res.json();
 setPosts(posts);
 }
getData();
return ()=> getData();
},[])
```

Comment: that didn't work i noticed that even removing the request i always get the same error